# Filter report based on the role in Cognos BI

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

I have a report in Cognos BI with a field where stored username.
A customer wanted to filter data report based on the user who runs this report.
I used filter [report].[user_name]=#sq($account.defaultName)#
and it works.
But now the customer wants to show all data in the report for one specific role in Cognos BI.
Is there any way how can I do that?

Comment: I found this article

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_fm.doc/c_usingthecsvidentitynamelistmacrofunction.html

Comment: it's good point but this macro gives me syntax error

Comment: but if I use this in_range  {#CSVIdentityNameList(";")#} it works perfiect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a boolean expression. Adjust it to do what you want:

```
(
[user_name]=#sq($account.defaultName)#
OR
[user_name]='The user name that can see everything'
)
```

Don't forget the brackets.

Comment: Hello, NIck, yes, you're right, you can't use if condition in the filter. I spent some time to figure this out.